# Identity Server 4 / Single SignOut and SignOut from External IdP at the same time

Tags: openid-connect, identityserver4

I have an IdentityServer 4 host, acting as IdP for several apps. IdSrv uses an external provider for user authentiction. On SignOut request from any app I have to close all existing sessions for the user.
Single signout using FrontChannelLogoutUri works fine.
External Sign out works fine when follow the [documentation](http://identityserver4test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/signout_external_providers.html), but my external IdP does not support redirect URLs, so the question is: ***how to call both internal SignOutIframeUrl and SignoutUrl on external provider at the same time?*** For now I've just added an IFrame with external logout url directly to LoggedOut view, but probably some better approach exists? Anyway it would be nice to see an example of similar configuration in the docs!